# Issues with Dictionary ToList serialization

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, dictionary

I tried to serialize the values of a dictionary using the ToList option.
I found out that in the deserializtion process I got null on all the object that I serialized
It didn't happen when I used memory stream and it didn't happened when I used .Net object as the type in the dictionary.
Below is an example code I created that shows the problem
The output of this code is 
Dictionary: 0-0
Dictionary: 1-1
List: 0
List: 1
Dictionary: 0-Null
Dictionary: 1-Null
List: 0

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A state = new A();

        Stream stream = File.Open("D:\\temp\\temp.txt", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, state);
        stream.Close();

        state.PrintData();

        stream = File.Open("D:\\temp\\temp.txt", FileMode.Open);
        bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        state = (A)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        state.PrintData();
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class A : ISerializable
{
    Dictionary<int, B> dic = new Dictionary<int, B>();
    List<B> list = new List<B>();

    public A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            dic.Add(i, new B(i));
            list.Add(new B(i));
        }
    }

    public void PrintData()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, B> kvp in dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: " + kvp.Key.ToString() + "-" + ((kvp.Value != null) ? kvp.Value.ToString() : "Null"));
        }
        foreach(B b in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List: " + b.ToString());
        }
    }

    public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        List<int> keys = info.GetValue("keys", typeof(List<int>)) as List<int>;
        List<B> values = info.GetValue("values", typeof(List<B>)) as List<B>;

        int count = keys.Count;
        if(count == values.Count)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dic[keys[i]] = values[i];
            }
        }

        list = info.GetValue("list", typeof(List<B>)) as List<B>;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("keys", dic.Keys.ToList(), typeof(List<int>));
        info.AddValue("values", dic.Values.ToList(), typeof(List<B>));
        List<B> listFromDic = new List<B>(dic.Values.ToList());
        info.AddValue("list", listFromDic, typeof(List<B>));
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class B : ISerializable
{
    int foo;

    public B(int i)
    {
        foo = i;
    }

    public B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foo = info.GetInt32("foo");
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("foo", foo);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (foo != null) ? foo.ToString() : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize the dictionary as a list? `Dictionary` is directly serializable.

Comment: because dictionary serialization was changed in .NET4 and there is a problem to support old serializations

Comment: Hi, Shimi, Would do you like to highlight "dictionary serialization was changed in .NET4 and there is a problem to support old serializations" in the question. So other viewer will knows that. I thought the forward-compatibility of .net 4 is better than .net 2.0

Comment: Hi The problem with the serialization isn't a forward compatibility it is with backward compatibility, if you serialize a dictionary in .Net4 you can't deserialize it in previous .Net, As I understand this is because they added internal comparer. The solution is in my code as well. but I am not sure why it happened, I assume that this is because the output of ToList isn't serializable but I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is supported by Serialize. here is the code I modified which works.

```
    public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        dic = info.GetValue("mapping", typeof(Dictionary<int, B>)) as Dictionary<int, B>;
        list = info.GetValue("list", typeof(List<B>)) as List<B>;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("mapping", dic, typeof(Dictionary<int, B>));
        List<B> listFromDic = new List<B>(dic.Values.ToList());
        info.AddValue("list", listFromDic, typeof(List<B>));
    }
```

**Edit:** 
op mentioned must use List. Revised code as following. Dictionary dic can't be initialized in constructor public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context).
Because:
**The order in which objects are deserialized cannot be guaranteed. For example, if one type references a type that has not been deserialized yet, an exception will occur. If you are creating types that have such dependencies, you can work around the problem by implementing the IDeserializationCallback interface and the OnDeserialization method.**

above para comes from: [ISerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)

which means B is not created In A's constructor.

Revised Code:

```
[Serializable()]
public class A : ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback 
{
    Dictionary<int, B> dic = new Dictionary<int, B>();
    List<B> list = new List<B>();
    private List<int> keys = new List<int>();

    public A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            dic.Add(i, new B(i));
            list.Add(new B(i));
        }
    }

    public void PrintData()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, B> kvp in dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: " + kvp.Key.ToString() + "-" + ((kvp.Value != null) ? kvp.Value.ToString() : "Null"));
        }
        foreach (B b in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List: " + b.ToString());
        }
    }

    public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        keys = info.GetValue("keys", typeof(List<int>)) as List<int>;
        List<B> values = info.GetValue("values", typeof(List<B>)) as List<B>;

        list = info.GetValue("list", typeof(List<B>)) as List<B>;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("keys", dic.Keys.ToList(), typeof(List<int>));
        info.AddValue("values", dic.Values.ToList(), typeof(List<B>));
        List<B> listFromDic = new List<B>(dic.Values.ToList());
        info.AddValue("list", listFromDic, typeof(List<B>));
    }

    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<int, B>();
        int count = keys.Count;
        if (count == list.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dic[keys[i]] = list[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Nice. Works for me. BTW, remove commented out code in `A()` constructor so quality of the answer would be better

Comment: I didn't use dictionary serialization because dictionary serialization was changed in .NET4 and there is a problem to support old serializations